# How to pass the Result of my CustomDotNet Activity to my stored procedure

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've created a ADF for my project,which consist of a Custom Activity and stored procedureactivity.

The thing I'm blocked here is.

My custom activity does the obtain the most recent modified file - let's assume `xx.txt` is the file - from  in my Azure Blob Container.

My stored procedure has the single parameter `FileName`. I want to pass the file name to my stored procedure which can be obtained from the above custom activity.
(We can say simply as my stored procedure activity input depends on the Custom Activity output)

How can I do this in my ADF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do this with two separate activities (maybe in two separate pipelines, if you want greater control) and using some middle ground storage that both processes can access.

For example:

1. Input dataset, Blob.
2. Custom activity.
3. Output dataset, SQL DB.
4. Input dataset, SQLDB (same as 3).
5. Stored Proc activity.
6. Output dataset, SQLDB.

It is the staging area datasets used for point 3 and 4 that is most important here.

This is how ADF will want to handle it. Although I understand why you would want to pass the output for the custom activity straight to the stored procedure, without using an additional dataset.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I initially assumed that there is a way to call directly from the customactivity result to Storeprocedure activity .But now i'm clear.Thanks